# Избавиться от предупреждения об отсутствии аргумента в методе класса

Tags: php, классы, методы, warning

Добрый день! Есть класс, в нем есть метод в который передаются аргументы.

`$answer = $orders->getOrders($limit);`

Бывают ситуации в которых эти аргументы могут и не передаваться, но при этом появляется предупреждение:

> Missing argument 1 for Orders::getOrders()

Как можно от него избавиться?

Answer (score 2):

Задать значение по-умолчанию в описании метода

```
function getOrders($limit = NULL)
{
    if(isset($limit)){

    }
}
```

Либо объявить метод без параметров и работать через func_get_args()

```
function getOrders()
{
    $arg = func_get_args();
}
```

Comment: Я классы пока только изучаю и не со всем разобрался. Я так понимаю что тут не прокатит как в обычной функции, что если аргумент не передан, то нет ни каких предупреждений, тут его в любом случае передавать нужно?

Comment: @ДенисГорев смотрите первый вариант в ответе

Comment: @ДенисГорев В обычных функциях всё работает точно так же, насколько я знаю.

Comment: @Mrak Проверил и точно в обычных функциях тоже предупреждение есть, что-то я напутал)